# Menubar made in Html, hover and selection effect

Tags: html, css, menubar

```
<div id="zgoraj">
                <a  href="">Domov</a>
                <a   href="">Moj profil</a>
                <a   href="">Administracija</a>
                <a  href="" >Urejanje urnikov</a>
                <a   href="">Statistike</a>
            </div>
<style>
#zgoraj{
width:670px;
background-color:#FF8000;
height:54px;

}
#zgoraj a{
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:black;
padding-top: 20px;
display:block;
float:left;
width:130px;
height:30px;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
text-align:center;
/*box-shadow: 0 -7px 22px 6px #000000 inset;*/
}
#zgoraj a:hover{
    color:black;
    background-color:white;

}

</style>
```

This is the code for my "menubar". When A link is selected and you are redirected to the specified url I would like the  the hover effect to stay on(I will edit href attributte).

Comment: When a linked is clicked a new page will load so why would it matter what happens to the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have the same menu in the top of each page, you need to update your CSS to add an extra class definition to your hover style:

```
#zgoraj a:hover, #zgoraj a.active {
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
```

and then add 'class="active"' to the <a> element that should be highlighted.

Comment: I added class="active" in each page to the page that is selected.